# preg replace with multiple curly brackets

Tags: regex, preg-replace, special-characters

I want to replace what is between the }string{ with }string%{

I'm adding the the `%` to edit a search query.

string example -
{a26f089ed1530be8648027b493a21bfd44c5fb15d632afc8f1c539c7c3da88a4}out{a26f089ed1530be8648027b493a21bfd44c5fb15d632afc8f1c539c7c3da88a4}

The 2 values between the pair of curlies changes each time `{rAndows2ring}`

I've tried a lot of variations and closest I've got to is;

```
$where = preg_replace("/\}([^}]+)\{/", "}$1%{", $where);
```

But that returns an extra % at the first {.

```
%{212190298d692385253efb2a1062006ddf3ea008e3cdc2f8b8f11884ec863202}out%{212190298d692385253efb2a1062006ddf3ea008e3cdc2f8b8f11884ec863202}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: [It does not](https://regex101.com/r/Rzggzl/1), it works as expected. Show the code.

Comment: You may just add `{` to the negated character class, `\}([^{}]+)\{`, to make sure there are no `{` and `}` between `}` and `{`.

Comment: odd - will check but that is the code and its output.

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
<?php

$oldString = '{a26f089ed1530be8648027b493a21bfd44c5fb15d632afc8f1c539c7c3da88a4}out{a26f089ed1530be8648027b493a21bfd44c5fb15d632afc8f1c539c7c3da88a4}';
echo '<p>oldString: ';
var_dump($oldString);
echo '</p>';


$newString = preg_replace('#(\{[\d\w]+\})([\d\w]+)(\{[\d\w]+\})#', '$1$2%$3', $oldString);

echo '<p>newString: ';
var_dump($newString);
echo '</p>';

?>
```

- (\{[\d\w]+\}) captures first string of digits and word characters enclosed with curly brackets.
- ([\d\w]+) captures 'out', or any other string of digits and word characters in between
- (\{[\d\w]+\}) same as above

Comment: OP code works well and the original regex is much cleaner and better than what you suggest.

Comment: It doesn't work at all if it puts another '%' where he doesn't want it.